# $64 = a^2-b^2$, how many solutions are there

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$64$ was written as a sum of two squares of two natural numbers. How many solutions does this equation have?

$$64 = x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$$

For example this works for $10$ and $6$, but how can I determine other solutions instead of just putting random numbers in there?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$ 64 = 2^6 $$

So we have, $64(1)$, $32(2)$, $16(4)$, $8(8)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that each of $x-y,x+y$ has to be *a positive divisor* of $64$.

Hence, noting that $x-y\le x+y$, we have
$$(x-y,x+y)=(1,64),(2,32),(4,16),(8,8)\Rightarrow (x,y)=(17,15),(10,6),(8,0).$$
(Note that $(x-y,x+y)=(1,64)$ does not lead integer solution.)